# Asp-classic Vbscript webpage language switcher into variable

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

For example i have language switcher in index.asp

```
            <ul class="drop-lang_menu">
                <li id="LanguageSelected"><img  src="img/icons/flags/ru.png" /><a href="#">Rus</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><img src="img/icons/flags/ru.png" /><a href="#">Rus</a></li>
                        <li><img src="img/icons/flags/lt.png" /><a href="#">Lit</a></li>
                        <li><img src="img/icons/flags/us.png" /><a href="#">Eng</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

and also in this file i have translate function for "Login" button text translate

```
<%=transl("Login")%>
```

This function is explained in file function.inc which included in index.asp

```
<%
Dim Lang

Lang = Document.getElementById("LanguageSelected").innerText

Function transl(TxT as String)
   Dim d
   d = Application("TranslateList")
   If d = "" Then 
      d = FetchTranslateList(TxT) 
      Application("TranslateList") = d
   End If
   transl = d
End Function


Function FetchTranslateList(TxT as String)
   Dim rs, fldName, s
   Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
   rs.Open "select "+Lang+" from Translations where txt='"+TxT+"'", _
           "dsn=name;uid=sa;pwd=;"
   s = "<select name=""Translations"">" & vbCrLf
   Set fldName = rs.Fields("+Lang+") 
   Do Until rs.EOF
     s = s & " <option>" & fldName _ 
             & "</option>" & vbCrLf
     rs.MoveNext
   Loop
   s = s & "</select>" & vbCrLf
   rs.Close
   Set rs = Nothing 
   Set fldName = Nothing 
   FetchTranslateList = s
End Function
%>
```

> Questions is:

1. Lang = Document.getElementById("LanguageSelected").innerText seem not working! So how to get selected language value and translate webpage for each user separately ?
2. Is that is right way to make webpage translation depending on language which user select on the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use asp to change language (document.getElement... is javascript!):

   ```
   <a href="index.asp?lang=rus">Rus</a></li>
   ```

then, lang = request.querystring("lang")

2. Other approach is create text files (rus.asp, esp.asp,...) with variables (txt_title="Titulo", txt_button_yes="Si",...) and includes one file or another depending of language. Include files is fast than query to database.

Another thing: is not a good idea create includes with .inc beacuse the code might be visible. Use .asp instead.

Answer (score 1):

`Document.getElementById("LanguageSelected").innerText` looks like client side Javascript.  ASP is server side code, it's executed when the page is served, so you'll need to populate your variable `Lang` either with a querystring value or a form submission and retrieve it with something like `Lang = request("Lang")`